# Relationship between position kets in different topologies

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, fourier-transform, discrete

Consider a particle moving on a ring $\mathcal{S}^1 \sim \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ of circumference $L$. Due to periodic boundary conditions,

$$
\langle x\mid p_n\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}e^{ip_{n}x/\hbar},\quad p_{n}=\frac{2\pi\hbar}{L}n
$$

where $\left|p_{n}\right\rangle $ are the momentum eigenstates. By acting on an arbitrary ket in the position basis, it is also possible to prove that the following completeness relation holds:

$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left|p_{n}\right\rangle \left\langle p_{n}\right|=\hat{I}
$$

Using these two relations, one can represent a position eigenstate on the circle as

$$
\left|x\right\rangle _{\mathcal{S}^1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ip_{n}x/\hbar}\left|p_{n}\right\rangle 
$$

However, in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.00010) paper, it is claimed that

$$
\left|x\right\rangle _{\mathcal{S}^{1}}=\sqrt{\frac{L}{2\pi\hbar}}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left|x+nL\right\rangle 
$$

where $x$ is limited to the interval $\left[0, L\right)$, the notation $\left| ~ \right\rangle _{\mathcal{S}^{1}}$ represents a state on the circle, and $\left| ~ \right\rangle$ is a state on the real line $\mathbb{R}$.

Intuitively I understand that $\left| ~ \right\rangle _{\mathcal{S}^{1}}$ must consist of all possible periodic "images" of the particle on the real line, but I wasn't able to prove this relationship. In particular, I do not understand how the normalization coefficient $\sqrt{\frac{L}{2\pi\hbar}}$ is obtained in this case.

I'm also not sure from a mathematical standpoint if it makes sense to relate $\left| ~ \right\rangle _{\mathcal{S}^{1}}$ to states $\left| ~ \right\rangle$ from the real line. It seems to me that these position eigenstates should belong to different (rigged) Hilbert spaces, because they represent systems with different topology. On the other hand, I don't know what is the proper way to incorporate topology in a Hilbert space.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I edited the question and added a link to the relevant paper (it corresponds to Eq. 4 in the paper).

Answer (score 1):

As you've written yourself, $S^1 = \mathbb R/L\mathbb Z$. This quotient extends to functions on the space. Start with a wave function $\psi: \mathbb R\to\mathbb C$, you can send it to a wave function on $S^1$ by periodising it $\psi\to \tilde\psi$:
$$
\tilde \psi(x) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\psi(x-nL)
$$
which can in turn be seen as a function on $S^1$, being factored by the canonical surjection. This is all what is claimed by the paper. They just write it in terms of position eigenkets, which can be viewed as a Dirac delta. In the language of distributions, you send a Dirac delta to a Dirac comb.

This allows to you capitalise the Fourier transform defined on $\mathbb R$ and understand the Fourier series via the Poisson summation formula.

Hope this helps.